# How to modify a directive for conditional display without container elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a simple role-based security directive in angularjs. This is my very first directive. What I'm trying to do is to replace this HTML:

```
<authorize if-granted="GET_POSTS">
    Hello WORLD!!!! {{name}}
</authorize>
```

with this:

```
Hello WORLD!!!! {{name}}
```

if the user have GET_POSTS privilege. Otherwise, I want to remove the element from DOM completely. My directive definition is as follows:

```
var securityModule = angular.module('securityModule', []);

securityModule.factory('security', function($http, $log) {
    var privileges = ['GET_ME', 'GET_POSTS'];

    return {
        hasPrivilege: function(privilege) {
            for (var i = 0; i < privileges.length; i++) {
                if (privileges[i] === privilege) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
});

securityModule.directive('authorize', function(security, $log) {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.transclude = true;
    directive.template = '<div ng-show="isAllowed" ng-transclude></div>';
    directive.scope = {};
    directive.replace = true;

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $log.info(attrs.ifGranted);

        scope.isAllowed = security.hasPrivilege(attrs.ifGranted);
    };

    return directive;
});
```

However, this replaces the directive tag with the following HTML:,

```
<div ng-show="isAllowed" ng-transclude="" if-granted="GET_POSTS" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        Hello WORLD!!!! Serdar Kuzucu
    </span>
</div>
```

I don't want to see this div and span tags. I want to see only the content of the directive.

Also, I don't want to use `ng-show`. Instead, I want to remove the element.

How can I modify my directive?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't remove the `<div>` and `<span>` elements which have angular control code on them;  how else would angular keep track of the changes it has made to the DOM and should make in the future?

Comment: Why are you returning a div as a template if you don't want a div in your page?

Answer (score 0):

For adding and removing element from DOM you could use `ng-if` instead directive instead of `ng-show`, `ng-if` will add/remove on basis of expression evaluated in its attribute value.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-if="isAllowed" if-granted="GET_POSTS" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        Hello WORLD!!!! Serdar Kuzucu
    </span>
</div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGKn5RRFXo1oLmJvArtX?p=preview)

Comment: if I change ng-show to ng-if, it throws this exception: Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdiv%20ng-if%3DNaNsAllowed%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%if-granted%3D%22GET_ME%22%20class%3D%22ng-scope%22%3E

Comment: could you check plunkr you need to remove `ng-transclude=""` from markup